# Continue iterating a 2D array from certain element

Tags: c#, loops, multidimensional-array, wordsearch

I am creating a word search game and I am stuck with the algorithm. I need to find the occurrences of a word in a table like data structure. I have chosen to use a 2d array for which I know the length and height. My idea is to look for the first letter of the word and if found to look in all possible directions. What I cannot grasp is how to start searching after I have found the first letter. I want to pass the location of the first letter to the methods that will search in all directions. Here is what I have so far:

```
 public void SearchWord(char[,] input, string name)
    {
        //1. loop through the array and look for the first letter of the string
        //2. if found search in all directions "iterative"
        //3. if one direction doesn't find it break out of the method and continue to search in other directions
        //4. if found mark the positions so you don't find the same word more than once
        char firstLetter = name[0];

        //go look for it in the 2d array
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                if (results[x, y] == firstLetter)//found the letter
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found it " + " " + firstLetter);
                    Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y);
                    SearchRightDirection(x, y);
                    SearchLeftDirection(x, y);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried passing the location as a parameter like SearchRightDirection(char[,], int x, int y){} however I cannot continue from this exact location row and column the array.

Do you have suggestions? Also if the structure is the right one?

Comment: What does the structure represent - some sort of a word dictionary? Why not simple `HashSet<string>`?

Comment: It is a two dimensional grid like N * M. If I use HashSet<string>, how would I  go about searching in diagonal direction?

Comment: My comment was on `Also if the structure is the right one?`. But probably I don't understand the use case - so it's a some sort of a game board, not just a word dictionary as in my first question? Why don't you remove that sentence, it's misleading.

Comment: Yep it is a game board like a cross word.

Comment: Is there some special symbol that indicates end of the word inside the `char[,]`? Also should we search for a whole word, i.e if we search for let say "as" and find "assume", is this counted as a match?

Comment: I need to count the occurrences of the word a the table. The word can be found horizontally, vertically and across both left to right and right to left. I am reading the data from a text file. I know the size of the table 4x5. There are no special characters, only chars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93622/discussion-between-henry-lynx-and-ivan-stoev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static class Sample
{
    public static int CountOccurrences(char[,] table, string word)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) return 0;
        int count = 0;
        int rowCount = table.GetLength(0);
        int colCount = table.GetLength(1);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
            {
                if (table[row, col] != word[0]) continue;
                if (word.Length == 1) { count++; continue; }
                for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++)
                    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++)
                        if ((dx != 0 || dy != 0) && Match(word, table, rowCount, colCount, row, col, dy, dx)) count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    private static bool Match(string word, char[,] table, int rowCount, int colCount, int startRow, int startCol, int dy, int dx)
    {
        int row = startRow + dy;
        if (dy != 0 && (dy < 0 ? row : rowCount - row) < word.Length - 1) return false;
        int col = startCol + dx;
        if (dx != 0 && (dx < 0 ? col : colCount - col) < word.Length - 1) return false;
        for (int charPos = 1; charPos < word.Length; row += dy, col += dx, charPos++)
            if (table[row, col] != word[charPos]) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```